# HTML form select field adds space above element when options have a value other than ""

Tags: html, css, forms, select

I have an html form element that is a `<select>` and whenever I add options and specify a value for the options, it adds a space/margin above the form select field. If I modify the code and set all options to `value=""` then the space/margin goes away.

```
<select id="authorizenet_cc_type" name="payment[cc_type]" class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select">
    <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="">American Express</option>
    <option value="">Visa</option>
    <option value="">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="">Discover</option>
</select>
```

The code above gives me:

[image]

But when I add values to each option, I get the following result:

[image]

How can I fix this to have the values set, but eliminate the space that it creates?

**EDIT:** It seems like it might be some sort of JavaScript code or something. When the page first loads it's OK for about 1 second, then once the placeholder info loads into all the other input fields, the space pops up.

Comment: We need a reproducible demo to help out. That isn't the default behavior for the HTML you posted.

Comment: I realize it's not the standard behavior for the HTML, hence the reason I completely baffled. It's on the checkout page of http://staging.everyonelovesbuttons.com. Add a custom button to the cart then click checkout, it will show up there.

Comment: It does seem to be progressive as well. In other words, the space/margin gets larger or smaller with the number of option elements in the select that have a value assigned. I am assuming it's some css somewhere, but what style could create that behavior?

Comment: If you check the DOM in the site you mentioned you will see that there is an UL element between the label "Credit Card Type" and the "select" element. Something in your code is probably adding this additional list as well, not only values in the select options. It is not an issue related to your select item (Actually you have similar elements which are working fine). I think no one will be able to help you if you don't provide more information about your code.

Comment: I'm not seeing a UL between the label and the select. There is a div, but it's not affecting it. The code pulled from source shows as:

Comment: `<li>
<label
for="authorizenet_cc_type" class="required"><em>*</em>Credit Card Type</label><div
class="input-box">
<select
id="authorizenet_cc_type" name="payment[cc_type]" class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select"><option
value="">--Please Select--</option><option
value="AE">American Express</option><option
value="VI">Visa</option><option
value="MC">MasterCard</option><option
value="DI">Discover</option>
</select></div></li>`